# How to lock combobox for typing

Tags: c#, devexpress

I use `DevExpress 2.4` and I have a combobox which is bound to a row in a propertygrid control. I want to disable this combobox for editing it content by keyboard and be able only to choose the value by clicking with the mouse. I read on the internet just to change the `DropDownStyle` property to `DropDownList`, instead of `DropDown` but when I go to the combobox in properties I don't have property  `DropDownList` and only `DropDownItemHeight` and `DropDownRows`... So how to disable typing in this combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the [LookupEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) control?

Answer (score 12):

Open property editor for this `GridControl` and open repository, now in options of this `ComboBox` go down to `TextEditStyle` and choose `DisableTextEditor` as option.

Comment: This is still valid as of version 14.1

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:
this.comboBoxType.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

Answer (score 1):

the point about setting the DropDownStyle they have told you is right for standard .NET Framework windows forms DropDowsLists, the DevExpress one you are using is a different control which offers a much richer API and feature set.

I have used the XtraEditors very much in the past and I was always able to get what I needed, can't remember now the exact property name but surely there is a property to do what you need now, not exposed to the main control, try to check the properties of the current editor in your combo box.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET, we do as :

```
    ComboBoxEdit1.Properties.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor
```

I hope there will be similar for C#.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Grid Control Repository Item has its own properties. You could view it by

Run Designer **->** Repository **->** In-place Editor Repository

Select the item you wish to edit the property. Explore those properties and you would love the manipulation of the properties.

BTW, just change the `TextEditStyle` property to `DisableTextEditor`.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Example : Two Mehtods
Disable Editing or Lock  ComboBox

Through code Simple Code:

```
DropDownListName.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Using Design Properties of Visual Studio:

Set  (DropDownList : DropDownList)

I hope this well Help you.

Answer (score 0):

C#
   This locks Combobox manual input and displays only comboboxlist items

```
this.yourcomboBoxname.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```